# Background Color element name in Visual Studio

Tags: themes, visual-studio-2022

I am using Visual Studio Color Theme designer.  I just need to know what property sets the background here. I'd like to set it to the same color as the rest of the background. I've tried setting all the tooltip options I can find.

[image: Screenshot - Visual Studio ToolTip]

Edits:

After changing various tooltip options:
[image: Updated options]

disabled selections in the options dialog:
[image: Options Dialog]

Comment: Is this what you want to achieve? https://i.stack.imgur.com/4F9dH.png I set the background to a bright green.

Comment: @TimothyG. I want the background to be one solid color just like your image shows.  I am looking for the explicit property names to change the text with the pure black background to the gray background the rest of the tool tip.

Comment: You can try my answer I just posted. That is how I made it a solid lime green.  I'm not sure about the pure black background behind the text. For me, that was also controlled by the same "Tooltip" property. I couldn't find one that is distinct to the text *background* only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whatever reason, it seem the properties are split between two categories.  I think the one you want to use is the `Tooltip` option under the "Environment" category.  In my screenshot, I've set it to a bright green (`FF22Cf46`):

[image: setting that you need to change]

This is what it ends up looking like.  I've also modified the tooltips border to be red (the `ToolTipBorder` option under "Environment"), and the text (of the description) to be blue (the `Plain Text` option under the "Editor Tooltip" category):

[image: tooltip with bright colors]

Comment: Those settings didnt work.  I added a new image in the question above for reference.

Comment: @JoeK I had a feeling that might happen. The portion that is darker I feel is graphically bugged. But I'll check again. You didn't make a change by chance to a control to that color previously did you?

Comment: Not that I know of.  I did find it interesting the two 'ToolTip' editor options under 'ToolTips'. the top one is the background and the bottom one is the foreground.  When you open those in Tools>Options>Fonts and Colors>Editor ToolTip the 'Background' option is disabled, but it will reflect the changes in Theme Designer.  It may have to do with whatever is disabling that option.

Comment: @JoeK Yea I am pretty sure something is bugged on your end.  When I change Environment→Tooltip, the entire box changes, but for you, only the portions without the text change (and only certain parts).  This leads me to believe that there isn't a dedicated "background" property for the text in this window.  Is this how your visual studio always displayed the text in these tooltips? If so, I'm 99.9% sure thats a weird bug (and maybe you should do a reinstall)

Comment: @JoeK I am also wondering if that item is disabled because _it doesn't exist_.

Comment: Or there is some other plain text backgound overriding it.  I put another image up above showing the options dialog.  I also applied the default Monokai - Pro theme, and had the same results.  Yea maybe I should do a clean install, and see what happens

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253590/discussion-between-joe-k-and-timothy-g).